# Servlet Mapping fails

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

Now I have the following problem:
I am trying to create a website using Tomcat 7 and JSP.
But I am not capable of configurating the server properly.
I want a website that shows in the browsers address-bar something like mydomain.com/about without any *.jsp or *.html.
In order to realize this I have a redirection Bean, that is called by a JSP-Page, parses the requested URI and returns the path of a JSP-File that should be forwarded to. The problem is the servlet mapping in the web.xml
There i tried to create a servlet mapping for e.g. /about that is mapped to the redirect.jsp that calls the bean. The problem is, that I recieve the following exception:

javax.servlet.ServletException: No servlet class has been specified for servlet redirect

Here is the code of the web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/engine</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

BTW: The index.jsp is called properly because it is in the welcome-file-list. The problem is redirecting to the other sites without displaying their path in the address-bar.

Maybe there is a way to forward in a Javabean. This could be called by the `<servlet-class>`-tag in the servlet mapping.

Thanks for your help in advance!
Max

Answer (score 4):

> *No servlet class has been specified for servlet redirect*

This error just means that there's no servlet with the name `redirect` been definied in `web.xml` like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.YourServletClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

or

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/redirect.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
```

Fix your `web.xml` accordingly.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I recommend to use a single `Filter` with some (XML?) config file for this instead. Something like [Tuckey's URL rewrite filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), which is much similar to Apache HTTPD's `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,
this is just one block above in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <description>The main redirection thing</description>
    <jsp-file>/jsp/redirect.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/engine</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Not the solution.
Im quite sure, the  wants a  node where the servlet is defined.
But as I said, I need a JSP-File instead.